# PHP function to MySQL function

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone give me a direction how I can rewrite this function as a MySQL function to be able to make this decode directly on MySQL?

```
const CHAR_MAP = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz0123456789';

function decode($encoded) {
    $elen = strlen($encoded);
    $cmlen = strlen(Mobile::CHAR_MAP);
    $offset = strpos(Mobile::CHAR_MAP, substr($encoded, 0, 1), 1);

    $decoded = '';
    $check = 0;
    for ($i=1;$i<$elen-1;$i++) {
        $a = strpos(Mobile::CHAR_MAP, substr($encoded, $i, 1), 1);
        $x = $a - $offset * $i;

        $x %= $cmlen;

        if ($x < 0) {
            $x = $cmlen + $x;
        }

        $decoded .= $x;

        $check += $x;

    }


    return $decoded;

}
```

Comment: I don't think it would run faster.

Comment: You may want to not push code into MySQL. If you ever needed to change databases then you'd have to rewrite this code, whereas written in PHP you could more easily apply it to different database backends.

Comment: Trying to work out what the function is trying to acheive. `$x` is a number between 0 and 35, so `$decoded .= $x` doesn't make sense. I suspect it should be `$decoded .= substr(CHAR_MAP,$x,1)` or something like that? In any case, this is a trivial little ROT-x decoder; PHP has a built in [str_rot13() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) though it's such a trivial encoding mechanism that I can't imagine why anyone would bother using it. More usefully if you're looking to improve your speed, the comments on that page include variants of your function with better performance

Comment: @SDC The function as is was used for existing data, means I can not change it, the function as is works within PHP but I woule like to have it on MySQL available. To Chris You're right, but this data exist now in the database and I'm looking for a way to access it without PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, against my better judgement I've hacked together a quick SQL function for you.

I should note that SO is not intended as a site where people write the whole answer for you, but rather where you get learn how to write the answer for yourself. However in this case, I couldn't see how to teach without just giving the answer, so here it is.

But please note: I HAVE NOT TESTED THIS *AT ALL*. I typed it directly into the SO answer box, it hasn't been anywhere near an actual mySQL server. If it doesn't work (which is highly likely), please try to fix it yourself before asking for any further help (and consider that as part of the answer to help you learn how it works).

Also note, I have made an assumption that the guess I made in the comments about your original PHP function having a bug is accurate. This SQL function does a character shift operation on the string; it doesn't output a string of useless digits.

```
delimiter ||
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS mydecode||
CREATE FUNCTION mydecode( x longtext) RETURNS longtext
LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA 
BEGIN
DECLARE len INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE cpos INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE output LONGTEXT;
DECLARE charmap LONGTEXT;
DECLARE cshift VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE thischar VARCHAR(1);
DECLARE thischarpos INT UNSIGNED;

SET charmap = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz0123456789';
SET len = LENGTH(x);
SET cpos = 1;
SET cshift = POSITION(SUBSTRING(x,len,1) IN charmap);

REPEAT
  SET thischar = SUBSTRING(x,cpos,1);
  SET thischarpos = POSITION(thischar IN charmap) + 35;
  SET output = CONCAT_WS(output,SUBSTRING(charmap,thischarpos-cshift,1));
  SET cpos = cpos + 1;
  UNTIL cpos >= len END REPEAT;
return output;
END;
||
```

I would re-iterate the other point I made in the comments about this being a trivial operation. Simple character shift operations like this are pretty useless really. There aren't any scenarios that I can think of where they're a good idea. Particularly not security.

If this "encoder" is being used for anything you consider as part of your security, then you have a very serious problem.

Comment: Thanks it don't give any result back, but I will now go trough it step by step and try to fix it.